# I don't know what make my app stopped unfortunately

Tags: java, android

- I am making my app with Tab in actionbar using Fragment. My code below:

  - Tab1Fragment.java & Tab2Fragment is the same

    ```js
    public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment{
        String list[] = new String[]{
                "apple", "bluecherry", "cherry", "coconut cream"
        };
     /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.ListFragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,android.view.ViewGroup,android.os.Bundle) */
    @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablist,container,false);
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vị trí vừa chọn: " + position + "," + "với nội dung" + getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    ```
  - Main Activity:

```js
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("List").setTabListener(this));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Custom").setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(tab.getPosition()==0){
            Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, tab1).commit();
        } else if(tab.getPosition()==1){
            Tab2Fragment tab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,tab2).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }
}
```

- My main_activity.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

- tablist.xml & tabcustom.xml is the same:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My app is targeting API 14: Android 4.0(IceCreamSandwich). I have found 3 days and can't understand why this app stop when it start.

- LogCat error:

```js
11-26 14:23:01.544 3417-3417/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10068: Read-only file system
11-26 14:23:01.544 3417-3417/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
11-26 14:23:01.545 3417-3417/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-26 14:23:01.692 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.053 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.089 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.111 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.132 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.149 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.166 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.182 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.199 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.215 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.232 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hoang.b13-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
11-26 14:23:02.233 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hoang.b13-1/lib/x86
11-26 14:23:02.235 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-26 14:23:02.271 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-26 14:23:02.272 3417-3417/com.example.hoang.b13 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.hoang.b13, PID: 3417
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hoang.b13/com.example.hoang.b13.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.hoang.b13.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-26 14:23:03.996 3417-3417/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3417 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: i have edited this post with LogCat.

Comment: @Wiliam Your log has a solution. look at it. they show you ActionBar is NULL.

Comment: Oh no, this mean i have to create an actionbar?

Comment: @Wiliam first of all, when you use getActionBar() or getSupportActionBar(), you have to check if it's NULL or not.

Comment: @Wiliam Can I see your theme for MainActivity?

Comment: Can you make some suggest for me? i am newbie :(

Comment: @kimkevin Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar ?

Comment: @Wiliam I suggest you to use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`. It will be solved

Comment: @kimkevin thank you :*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity to have Actionbar with fragments.

still Try to below code

```
ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

more detail see this
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: Not exist getSupportActionBar();

Comment: post your theme

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: @Wiliam see my updated answer

Comment: i can't use (ActionBarActivity) , error cant resolve symbol

Comment: @Wiliam happy to help you

Comment: because i use appcompat theme, then i must use getSupportActionBar

Comment: thank you again <3